# Navigation bar Title bar button text not truncating string by tail

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have created navigation bar with left bar button items using story board. Left bar button items include menu button, title button and search button as shown on below picture :
[image: Left bar items with navigation drawer]

When i run the app with short text for title button it works fine as shown below: [image: Short Text]

Problem is when the text is long which makes other button disappear as shown below :
[image: long text problem]

Title bar button text is not truncating string by tail after changing text.
below is the code i'm using to change text

```
 TitleButton.setTitle(String(titleString.uppercased()) ,for: UIControl.State.normal)
```

After changing title text using above code, Title text style changed, text is overlapping and other bar items disappearing.

is there a way to force title button to truncate tail ?

Comment: try with `TitleButton.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 1`

Comment: Do you really want a button there? Or do you just want a title in the nav bar?

Comment: @FahimParkar I tried the code and it does not work for button

Comment: @Fogmeister i need the button to be on title bar to be able to open drop down list

Comment: You have to create a custom view and add it to the titleView of the navigationBar. self.navigationItem.titleView = yourView
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false